# Node JS get request body length

Tags: node.js

I need to get the length of a field in req.body. But using `req.body.username.length <= 5` I got error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. How can I do it?

Comment: The error is regarding, username? You need to make sure you get a username.
So first log out if you are getting 
    req.body && req.body.username

Comment: username is array then only it can return length

Answer (score 2):

Consider that objects don't has property `length` in JavaScript. For this purpose you can use this code instead.

```
Object.keys(req.body).length
```

`Object.keys(req.body)` will return an array of all keys. So, we can simply get the length of an array with `.length`.

Comment: this only get amount of keys, not the whole content-length

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to use the middleware `body-parser` to parse the body before accessing the data in it.

Install it using the command:

```
npm install body-parser
```

Use it like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies. This parser accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Returns middleware that only parses json. This parser accepts any Unicode encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.
```

NPM reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: I forget to mention that I use it inside a function. I can use it inside router.post(). The error is `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: @NoName Can you please confirm if there is really `username` inside `req.body` ?

Comment: I have found what cause the error. My username is empty

Answer (score 0):

This issue can have two possibilities.

1)req.body is undefined. It means you are not able to parse the body.To overcome this do follwing steps.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

include following lines in your app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('json spaces', 1);
```

2.Another possibility which i can think of is If your req.body is parsed properly but you dont have a key named username in req.body

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.  I wasn't getting anything in my Object.keys(req.body).  I found the reason was because I was sending raw text in the POST body instead of JSON.  So make sure you are sending valid JSON.