# How can I know how many elements does req.body holds?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been learning *express.js* and *node js* recently, and I'm developing a questionnaire form which posts the relevant parameters to the server. I'd like to know if my clients complete all questions. How can I check how many elements are in `req.body`.

Does `req.body` has the property `.length`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can do `Object.keys(req.body).length`.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019030/node-js-get-request-body-length Also some code would help

Comment: Sorry, but what I want to know is the length of req.body rather than the length of one element in req.body. Still, thx

Comment: The body of an HTTP request can be anything. It could be a base64 encoded video file. "Length" is meaningless unless you are more specific about *what* you are sending and how you are parsing it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to parse req.body for that. I recomend to use some kind of bodyparser middleware. Once you get it parsed, it should give an object, and there you can count the keys of that object. ie

```
var count = Object.keys(myParsedBodyObject).length
```

Comment: Happy to help. Could you validate the answer please?